# Javascript - Check if cookie is set

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies

Hi everyone i want to redirect a user to another page if the cookie is set by clicking the button.

```html
<a href="" onClick="SetCookie('pecCookie','dit is een cookie','-1')"><button type="button" name="accept" class="btn btn-success">Button Text</button> 
<script>
    function SetCookie(c_name,value,expiredays)
        {
            var exdate=new Date()
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+365)
            document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+
            ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString()) +
            ("; path=/")
      location.reload()
        }
        
    if 
        
</script>
```

Works and i also got the if statement in php but i want it in javascript because of wordpress issues. In php it would look like this.

```
    <?php
$cookie_name = "anyname";
$cookie_value = "anycontent";
If (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
// action if cookie is set  
}
?>
```

i can't seem to figure it out in javascript, and i also looked around on the web

After doing this:

```html
<a href="" onClick="SetCookie('pecCookie','dit is een cookie','-1')"><button type="button" name="accept" class="btn btn-success">Button Text</button> 
<script>
    function SetCookie(c_name,value,expiredays) {
            var exdate=new Date()
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+365)
            document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+
            ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString()) +
            ("; path=/")
      location.reload()
        }
       
    mycookieValue = getCookie("pecCookie")
    if(mycookieValue) {
        window.location = "193.91.113.21/downloads/";
    }
    
function getCookie(c_name) {
    var re = new RegExp(c_name + "=([^;]+)");
    var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
    return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
}
        
</script>
```

it keeps going to the redirect even without the cookie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function for get the cookie value in javascript.

```
mycookieValue = getCookie("mycookieName")

if(mycookieValue)
{
  //Your code here
}

function getCookie(name)
{
    var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
    var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
    return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
}
```

Comment: and with this i start an if statement then?

Comment: Yes you can start with setting a var with that function, and if its not undefined then the cookie exists

Comment: you mind helping me? Having a hard time figuring this one out ;o

Comment: Edited comment with the if statement

Comment: Thanks for the help dude. But now the problem is that the page links to the redirect everytime i visit even without the cookie. edited my post with your solution

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you use jQuery cookie.js library. You can download it from here.. https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Example:

```
 //Set Cookie
 $.cookie('userName', 'John');

//Read Cookie Value
var username= $.cookie('userName');
console.log(username);

//Remove a cookie
$.removeCookie('username'); 
//Cookie is removed then above line will return true

//Check cookie in if else

if(username){
  console.log(username);
}

// or you can do this also
if(username=='John'){
  console.log('User Name is '+username);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Well the problem with this is how do i implement this on wordpress?

Comment: first download cookie.js and then wp_enqueue_script to wordpress

Then add Javascript code any where in your theme. May be in footer.php just before </body>